# Runtime error in build_pdf module of latex - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, latex

Below is my latex_template.py file

```
min_latex = (r"\documentclass{article}"
             r"\begin{document}"
             r"Hello, world!"
             r"\end{document}")

from latex import build_pdf

# this builds a pdf-file inside a temporary directory
pdf = build_pdf(min_latex)

# look at the first few bytes of the header
print bytes(pdf)[:10]
```

When I try to run this file I get the following error:

```
python latex_template.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latex_template.py", line 9, in <module>
    pdf = build_pdf(min_latex)
  File "/home/psycane/test/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/latex/build.py", line 205, in build_pdf
    raise RuntimeError('No available builder could be instantiated. '
RuntimeError: No available builder could be instantiated. Please make sure LaTeX is installed.
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your're missiing the latex binaries.

On linux machines it's calles `texlive` --> [More infos](http://www.tug.org/texlive/)

For example Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

For OSX you can install [MacTex](https://tug.org/mactex/)

Answer (score 0):

If your system is ubuntu or debian, the solution is below.

```
sudo apt-get install latexmk
```

If your system is other linux distribution, you need to find solution to install "latexmk" by yourself.

You must haven't installed "latexmk" judged by "bool(which(self.latexmk))" in the following source code.You can test it in cmd tools with the cmd "which latexmk"

```
def build_pdf(source, texinputs=[]):
    """Builds a LaTeX source to PDF.
    Will automatically instantiate an available builder (or raise a
    :class:`exceptions.RuntimeError` if none are available) and build the
    supplied source with it.
    Parameters are passed on to the builder's
    :meth:`~latex.build.LatexBuilder.build_pdf` function.
    """
    for bld_cls in PREFERRED_BUILDERS:
        builder = bld_cls()
        if not builder.is_available():
            continue
        return builder.build_pdf(source, texinputs)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('No available builder could be instantiated. '
                           'Please make sure LaTeX is installed.')

def is_available(self):
    return bool(which(self.pdflatex)) and bool(which(self.latexmk))
```

The github link is https://github.com/mbr/latex/blob/master/latex/build.py.